# IIS SSL Certificate No longer visible from internet

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, iis-10

Pulling my hair out here. Yesterday I set up an SSL Certificate in IIS10. This is the process I followed:

1. In IIS, under Server Certificates complete Create Certificate Request (generated server.csr & server.key)
2. Go to sslforfree.com and start "create certificate" process.
3. Enter Static IP in Domain box
4. In Validity, choose paste Existing CSR (paste in contents of server.csr)
5. Select free 90 day certificate
6. Choose HTTP file upload and add auth file to virtual share in IIS.
7. Verified OK.
8. Download certificate
9. Back in IIS, select "Complete Certificate Request"
10. Browse to and select "certificate.crt" file.
11. Give it a friendly name etc, and save.
12. Browse to website under sites in IIS, and select Bindings. Choose the IP of the server, the incoming Port, and the newly imported SSL certificate.
13. Back in sslforfree, check the installation.
14. Everything all good

So everything was working beautifully, could see the certificate in the browser etc, job done.

Now come to today, and the server is actively refusing requests. Go back to check the installation of my SSL on sslforfree, and it's no longer found. Tried removing and re-adding, but nothing I do seems to get the SSL to be visible.

It's not that the certificate is refused, the browser doesn't even think it's there.  Why would IIS suddenly stop sharing the certificate? I am totally stumped.

**EDIT**

As per the advice below, I set up a DNS name with CloudFlare and pointed it at my server.

[image]

I Set up the bindings in IIS to link to the new hostname and removed the old certificate (one for port 443 and this one for port 4443 which the API runs on):

[image]

Ports 80, 443 and 4443 are all port-forwarded on the router to my server:

[image]

I then downloaded Win-ACME and successfully created the Let's Encrypt certificate, and the renewal task created in Task Scheduler.

[image]

SSL Cert now shows in Bindings:

[image]

SSL Certificate appears to be all good:

[image]

...but when I go to the site, using the new domain name.  Same problem... no certificate:

[image]

So I'm not sure what the problem is here...

[image]

Comment: As of today, I also opened the Port in the firewall, for no effect. This wasn't specified yesterday when it was working.

Comment: "Enter Static IP in Domain box" doesn't look good. Certificates need to bind to real domain names, not IP addresses.

Comment: @LexLi According to this unless it's an EV it's fine. https://www.geocerts.com/support/ip-address-in-ssl-certificate. Since it's domain validated, and I was able to validate the domain it should work. 

Problem seems to be that the certificate isn't being passed out by IIS to be verified.

Comment: It was working for a day, which is the most annoying part.

Comment: Failed Request Tracing is enabled and "C:\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles" is empty

All requests in C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1\*.log files are 200 successful.  The request gets through to the server and is responded to, but for whatever reason the certificate is not attached and isn't being verified.

Comment: Failed request tracing is of little help here. You need to analyze the certificate itself, as well as Windows HTTP API settings. I will suggest you use a true Let's Encrypt solution, other than that site, which is often more reliable on giving you a suitable certificate to bind on IIS.

Comment: @LexLi What's the cheapest way to get a dns name for my static IP? I don't want to spend a few hundred if it makes no difference.

Comment: A domain is rather cheap an asset (.com only costs 8.x USD a year) to own, https://www.cloudflare.com/products/registrar/ and some registrar even offers 1.x USD for the first year. So if you really want to run a web site, find a good domain and buy it.

Comment: @LexLi See EDITs

Comment: Sounds like a lot have been done. Can you run a report now? https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html Besides, you should now use `https://www.yoursite.com` (which uses port 443) to test, not `:4433`.

Comment: @LexLi it's only a Web API. 443 will return nothing. I'll try the report.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243959/discussion-between-devonuto-and-lex-li).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Lex Li, I was able to dig around with Jexus Manager, and IIS Crypto to work out what was wrong.

Seems having TLS 1.2 an TLS 1.3 enabled on my machine at the same time was causing issues.  Discovered this using Postman and disabling certain TLS Protocols, eventually getting it to work.

For those of you who may experience similar issues, using this application and setting it to "Best Practices" after disabling TLS 1.3 in my Registry, I finally have it working, with a certificate.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This issue may happens when the imported cert does not have a private key associated. solution would be to import the .CER file to your system(from where certificate is requested) personel store and export it with private key. Then copy the .pfx file to required server and import it from server certificate option under IIS.

And you can refer to this link: [The Whole Story of "Server Certificate Disappears in IIS 7/7.5/8/8.5/10.0 After Installing It! Why!"](https://blog.lextudio.com/the-whole-story-of-server-certificate-disappears-in-iis-7-7-5-8-8-5-10-0-after-installing-it-why-b66e802baa38).

Comment: Certificate definitely has a private key. Shows "you have a private key that corresponds to this cerificate" in the General tab of the certificate view.

Comment: Also tried refreshing the private key with:
certutil -repairstore my "<certificate thumbprint>"
But that made no difference. Starting to wonder if my ISP is blocking it somehow.

Comment: Thanks for linking to my blog post. But this guy created the request and completed it on the same machine, so the private key was well kept by IIS Manager.